# Convert Java Project into a Maven Java Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I`m looking for the best way to convert a Java Project into a Maven Java Project.

I have a Java Project with libraries store locally and I would like to convert this project into a Maven project.

I could do that. In Eclipse a right-clicked into the project > Configure > Convert to Maven Project.

Following these steps, eclipse creates the pom.xml with artifactId, groupId, versions and etc.

I would like to know if there is any way to update the pom dependencies, for instance:

The project has a lib folder which contains all libraries/dependencies of the project, I want to update pom.xml (automatically) with these libraries so Maven can download it automatically.

Are there any way to do that automatically or you suggest to do it manually (verifying the static dependency and update the pom.xml with this dependency).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no magic that I know of.  You have to see which ones are available in Maven Central.  Any JARs that are not available there will have to be added to your local .m2 or some other repo that's available to you.  You need to move your source to the Maven mandated directory structure as well.

Comment: [Search by SHA-1 checksum](http://blog.sonatype.com/2011/02/new-service-to-search-for-artifacts-in-maven-central/).

Comment: Very nice, but you can't find what isn't there.  JDBC JARs from Microsoft and Oracle are not available in Maven Central; neither are any component JARs that you build in house.

Comment: Just been doing something similar with an IBM project.  I find the jars and create artifacts of my own using mvn install:install-file